# Ubuntu 12.04 Home Folder

Tags: 12.04

I have recently installed ubuntu 12.04 along with windows 7. I have created a common partition for storing my media files which I want to access from both OS. Now I want to replace the default Home Folder menus (like Documents, Downloads etc...) with the one I have in my common storage. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I do the same with my setup (though I use a 2nd ext4 disc).

This is one of the post install actions I take from a terminal:

Once ...

```
cd /discworld2/
mkdir Desktop/ Downloads/ Pictures/ Videos/ Public/ Music/ Templates/ Documents/
```

Every time I reinstall ...

```
cd
rm -rf Desktop/ Downloads/ Pictures/ Videos/ Public/ Music/ Templates/ Documents/ 
ln -s /discworld2/Desktop/   Desktop
ln -s /discworld2/Documents/ Documents
ln -s /discworld2/Downloads/ Downloads
ln -s /discworld2/Pictures/  Pictures
ln -s /discworld2/Templates/ Templates
ln -s /discworld2/Videos     Videos
```

- The 2nd command will delete all content inside those directories.
- Change /discworld2/ to the directory you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Tweak, the GUI tool will do this work. It's under Admins -> User Folder

Comment: Ubuntu tweak makes life easier.............

Comment: i did used ubuntu tweak for it but after restarting my system its keep going back to its default location. How should i fix this?